# fastPOSIXct equivalent for converting non-UTC to UTC

Tags: r, posix, posixct

Hi I have a character vector (`rr`) that is several million in length, and it represents time and date stamps in the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` recorded in Australia/Sydney.

How do get a POSIXct object (quickly) that represents this.

I have found `fastPOSIXct` in the `fasttime` package, but for this to be accurate, it requires the original character string to be in GMT/UTC, (which mine is not) and then converted back into the correct timezone using the `tz` arguement...

```
> head(rr)
[1] "2009-05-01 10:01:00" "2009-05-01 10:02:00" "2009-05-01 10:03:00" "2009-05-01 10:04:00"
[5] "2009-05-01 10:05:00" "2009-05-01 10:06:00"

> as.POSIXct(head(rr),tz="Australia/Sydney")
[1] "2009-05-01 10:01:00 EST" "2009-05-01 10:02:00 EST" "2009-05-01 10:03:00 EST"
[4] "2009-05-01 10:04:00 EST" "2009-05-01 10:05:00 EST" "2009-05-01 10:06:00 EST"
```

The above line takes ages if doing it on the full set of data...so any speed improvements would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since a POSIXct datetime is just an underlying numeric vector, you could use `fastPOSIXct`, then add the required offset to convert from GMT to AEST.

Comment: How would you make the offsets object?

Comment: At the moment the problem is underspecified. Do these times have any "daylight savings times" in them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say ""daylight savings times" in them" but the character string, is basically the timestamp recorded as if you looked at the clock in Sydney at that time...so if you are in summer time it would have recorded it as it is...(if that makes sense)

Comment: if there are no *switches* in daylight savings time (i.e. the offset from UTC is constant across your data set), then Dirk's solution below will work.  Otherwise things will get progressively uglier and more complex and you'll find yourself re-implementing DST support ..

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Dirk's answer to this qn, I made this wrapper for handling a whole bunch of dates across the year:

```
    fastPOSIXct_generic <- function(x, mytz = "America/New_York")
{
    # Caution, read: ?DateTimeClasses
    stopifnot(is.character(x))
    times_UTC <- fastPOSIXct(x, tz='UTC')
    num_times <- as.numeric(times_UTC)
    t1 <- as.POSIXct(x[1], tz = mytz)
    t2 <- as.POSIXct(x[1], tz = "UTC")
    offset <- as.numeric(difftime(t1, t2, units = "secs"))
    daylightoffset <- as.POSIXlt(t1)$isdst
    # For this first 'time' in t1 and t2, remove possible impact of losing one hour by setting clocks one hour forward during summer months:
    offset <- offset + daylightoffset * 3600
    num_times <- num_times + offset
    new_num_times <- as.POSIXct(num_times, tz = mytz, origin = '1970-01-01')
    new_num_times2 <- new_num_times - as.POSIXlt(new_num_times)$isdst * 3600
    return(new_num_times2)
}

# Test Sydney time

mm <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-03-15 15:00:00", "2015-4-10 15:00:00", "2014-10-01 15:00:00", "2015-10-15 15:00:00"), tz = "Australia/Sydney")
# "2015-03-15 15:00:00 AEDT" "2015-04-10 15:00:00 AEST" "2014-10-01 15:00:00 AEST" "2015-10-15 15:00:00 AEDT"
aus_stamps <- as.character(mm)
aus_back <- fastPOSIXct_generic(x = aus_stamps, mytz = "Australia/Sydney")
#"2015-03-15 15:00:00 AEDT" "2015-04-10 15:00:00 AEST" "2014-10-01 15:00:00 AEST" "2015-10-15 15:00:00 AEDT"
identical(mm, aus_back)
# TRUE
```

My use cases are nearly always UTC to America/New_York, where so far it has seemed to work fine.  I don't know whether it works correctly for other time zones; just the cases where dst has time go forward an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

i)  Lie to `fasttime()` and pretend the data was UTC, use to parse the data into a vector `x`

ii) Compute an offset to UTC using your first data point:

```
R> d1 <- "2009-05-01 10:01:01"   ## or use `head(rr,1)`
R> t1 <- as.POSIXct(d1,tz="Australia/Sydney")
R> t2 <- as.POSIXct(d1,tz="UTC")
R> offset <- as.numeric(difftime(t2, t1, units="secs"))
R> offset
[1] 36000
```

iii) Apply the `offset` value to your data -- that is a quick addition as `POSIXct` really is a numeric type with (fractional) seconds (since epoch) as its unit.

Comment: As mentioned in @Ben Bolker's comment, this approach only works if the recorded timezone does not adhere to daylight savings, i.e. the offset to GMT/UTC is always constant...also I'm not too sure the `d2` object is the third line of your code...

Comment: We usually deal with a few 100k of data from within a day, so crossing  TZ is usually not an issue--and as Ben noted, a common alternative is to parse *all* the time strings which is expensive. `d2` was a typo, should have been `d1` too --fixed.